# Confusion regarding what kind of isomorphism is intended.

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

For a class I'm taking this semester, I was given this question:

(To guarantee clarity, I am quoting the full question even though my own question is only regarding the final sentence.)

*Let $G$ be a finite group. If $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}G$-module, then $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(V)$ denotes the ring of $\mathbb{R}G$-module endomorphisms of $V$ (where the multiplication is composition). If $V$ is simple, then by the same argument as in the proof of Schur's Lemma part (1), every nonzero element of $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(V)$ has a two-sided inverse.*

*(i) Prove that the converse is true: if every non-zero element of $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}G}(V)$ has a two-sided inverse, then $V$ is simple.*

*(ii) Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the quaternion ring, $Q$ the quaternion group $\{\pm 1,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ and $T : Q \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{H})$ the linear representation of $Q$ defined by $T(g)(v) = gv$. Regard $\mathbb{H}$ as an $\mathbb{R}Q$-module via the representation $T$. Show that $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}Q}(\mathbb{H}) \cong \mathbb{H}$.*

Now I have completed part (i), am attempting to do part (ii). My question is, $\text{End}_{\mathbb{R}Q}(\mathbb{H})$ denotes a ring, while $\mathbb{H}$ we are regarding as an $\mathbb{R}Q$-module, so exactly what kind of isomorphism are we to show exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R Q}(\mathbb H)$, you are regarding $\mathbb H$ as an $\mathbb R Q$-module, but in the isomorphism $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb R Q}(\mathbb H) \cong \mathbb H$, you are supposed to once more regard $\mathbb H$ as a ring (with its usual ring structure).

Comment: Ohh, my mistake, I see it now, thanks a lot (seems so simple now but I'm still a beginner with this subject, so am slow with things at times).

Comment: @MontyGill: Dear Monty, No worries; it's easy to see why this would be confusing.  Best wishes,

Comment: Surely this at least is correct, but superficially, since this is representation thoery, I would think that it might be $\mathbb{R}$-linear as well, so as to be an $\mathbb{R}$-*algebra* homomorphism. Is there a reason why this isn't so?

Comment: @rschwieb: Dear rschwieb, Of course the isomorphism will be an isomorphism of $\mathbb R$-algebras, but it sounds as if the OP is in a beginning algebra class, so it may well be that they haven't studied the notion of algebras over a field yet.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Ok, good to know!